# Are there any formulas/algorithms that could allow level to decide how many dice can be used for a roll?

Tags: rpg, random, combat

See, I'm trying to work on an cRPG system and I want a formula or algorithm I guess, where the level affects how many dice can be rolled for any action (in addition to a default number of dice and other calculations). Such as the following:

Lv.1-10: 1 dice

Lv.11-20: 2 dice

Lv.21-30: 3 dice

Lv.31-40: 4 dice

Lv.41-50: 5 dice

Lv.51-60: 6 dice

Lv.61-70: 7 dice

Lv.71-80: 8 dice

Lv.81-90: 9 dice

Lv.91-100: 10 dice

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking here. Do you want an algorithm which results in exactly that distribution? Or are you looking for a suggestion for how many dice to use per level? The latter is impossible to answer, because we have no idea what your game design goals are and how this mechanic fits into the rest of your game design.

Comment: I'm looking for the former. An algorithm that results in that exact distribution.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is.

```
numberOfDice = floor( ( Level - 1 ) / 10 ) + 1
```

The `floor` method will essentially take the integral part of the result of the division `(Level-1)/10` (it will round it down). If you're going to use any popular language or framework, I suggest you lookup the `floor` method.

I would also have suggested to rely on the integer division, but since it's not clear what will be your target language/framework, I don't know how it will behave. You could probably test it first. In this case, you would just have to drop the `floor` function:

```
numberOfDice = ( ( Level - 1 ) / 10 ) + 1
```

---

As a footnote, you could probably look up the JavaScript [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) function to get familiar with it.